# Sorting search result alphabetically

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a CSWP in my page  where I am getting all the subsite names under the site collection.

I wanted to sort it using title of site. So I have tried to edit managed property named `SiteTitle` but every option on page is grayed out.

My search query is

`path:"https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/" contentclass:STS_Web Site<>{Site.URL} {SearchBoxQuery}`

What should I don to get my search results sorted?
I am doing it in sharepoint online

Comment: Are you fetching names of subsites from term store?

Comment: I have written query to get subsutes only

Comment: Can you please your query here?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Try to create a new managed property, then map crawled properties to it and make this managed property sortable. After creating this property, re-crawled the site.

Comment: I have done this, and mapped property to ows_SiteName, but still it didnt worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57829/discussion-between-divya-sharma-and-kumarv).

Comment: Chat is blocked , i can not navigate to that page

Comment: Have you performed full-crawl after creating custom managed property?

Comment: I have observed that in SharePoint online, crawl is automatic. Do I need to crawl automatically

Comment: Try to manually request for crawling and re-indexing. Refer this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-request-crawling-and-re-indexing-of-a-site-a-library-or-a-list-9afa977d-39de-4321-b4ca-8c7c7e6d264e

Comment: OK, I will try it